# MySQL xml comparing with column data

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, xpath, xquery

Suppose you have a table '**Cities**' as following:

```
Id | CodeNumber | CityXml
```

And you have the following xml stored in your CityXml column

```
<record>
  <data code="10">istanbul</data>
  <data code="20">madrid</data>
</record>
```

And you want to get name of cities which have code=10. In order to do this, you can write:

```
SELECT 
ExtractValue(Cities.CityXml, '/record/data[code="10"][1]') AS CityName
FROM Cities
```

This works fine. My problem starts when the code number is given from an other column of the table:

```
/* this does not work */
SELECT 
CodeNumber,
ExtractValue(Cities.CityXml, '/record/data[code="CodeNumber"][1]') AS CityName
FROM Cities
```

In SQL Server, you can write the following statement:

```
SELECT 
CodeNumber,
ExtractValue(Cities.CityXml, '/record/data[code=sql:column("CodeNumber")][1]') AS CityName
FROM Cities
```

But how can you write this in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Build the XPath string using `CONCAT`

```
SELECT CodeNumber,
       EXTRACTVALUE(Cities.City, CONCAT('/record/data/[code="', CodeNumber, '"][1]') AS CityName
FROM Cities
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick response. I have tried this now and it returned: "only constant xpath querries are supported".

Comment: From this, will we infer that this type of design will not in mysql?

Comment: I think you may have to write a stored procedure that gets all the `CodeNumber`s, and then does a loop that uses `PREPARE` to create dynamic SQL for each code number.